# Groovy and gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have groovy version installed on Ubuntu 12.04. Now, I will like to install and know which gazebo version is recomended with groovy or if I have to use other Ros version. Any sugestions?

Also, maybe I will like to add simbody engine later.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135161/groovy-and-gazebo/) by [Gxav](https://answers.ros.org/users/12736/gxav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo 1.7.13 is packaged within ROS Groovy as the simulator_gazebo stack. You can install it on Ubuntu by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo
```

Groovy does not use the system-wide installation Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gxav](https://answers.ros.org/users/12736/gxav/) on 2014-03-04**:
Thank you very much